# Synapse Notebook reference - Call Synapse pipeline from Notebook

Tags: azure-synapse, spark-notebook

I'm trying to run a synapse pipeline from a synapse notebook, is there any way to do it?

My synapse pipeline has parameters, - if it's possible to run it from a notebook then how to pass the params?

Comment: Not sure if this would be blocked, although the pipelines do have a REST API but I mean, why not use a Synapse Pipeline to do the main orchestration and let notebooks do fun Spark things?

Comment: Yes, this (...use a Synapse Pipeline to do the main orchestration.....) works fine, I just wanted to treat a pipeline , with params , as a "tool" called from the Spark.

Comment: Yeah ok, but you probably need to think about cost too.  There’s always a 2-3 minute start up time for the Spark pools, plus you’ll have them running the whole time your pipeline is running?  Sounds expensive to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by **Wbob**, I would also recommend not doing this (calling synapse pipelines from synapse notebook) because of the spark pools.

But if you want to give a try, you can go through this approach other than REST API.

In this, I have added a **Storage event trigger to synapse pipeline** and it triggers by **writing to the storage using synapse notebook code**.

For this you required a Storage account and an empty container.

First create a **linked service for ADLS Gen2** in the synapse and a Storage event trigger to the synapse pipeline.

In the Synapse notebook, write a json file to ADLS which triggers the pipeline.
You can pass the parameters from synapse notebook using the same json.

**Code in the Synapse notebook with sample parameters:**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
myjson=[{"Name":"Rakesh","Age":22,"Marks":90}]
schema2=StructType([StructField('Name',StringType(),True),StructField('Age',IntegerType(),True),StructField('Marks',IntegerType(),True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=myjson,schema=schema2)
df.show(truncate=False) 

df2=df.toPandas()
df2.reset_index().to_json('abfss://input/myjson.json', storage_options = {'linked_service' : 'AzureDataLakeStorage1'},orient='records')
```

[image]

[image]

Here `input` is my container and `AzureDataLakeStorage1` is my linked service. `orient='records'` gives the indexes with the parameters.

This will create the `myjson.json` file in the ADLS container like below.

[image]

The above file triggers the Synapse pipeline. To use the parameters that we pass, use lookup activity in the pipeline.

**Lookup activity:**

In the lookup, don't give any dataset value in the dataset. give the wildcard path file as `*.json`.

[image]

**Look up will give the result like this:**

[image]

You can use the expression `@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].Age` and
`@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].Name` like these to access the parameters with their own data type in the synapse pipeline.

**For Example in set variable activity:**

[image]

**Output:**
As variables only supports Strings, Booleans and Arrays I have converted it to string for showing the output. You can use those parameters wherever you want.

[image]

Comment: ", I would also recommend not doing this" -> that's true.

But Rakesh great thanks for showing the way, if i'll be desperated i'll try it :)